# How to perform search operation on two fields with same keyword in hql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-search

I am not getting the record if any one of the field in data base is null whether the company name or location. Here `keyword` is what I am entering from the form.

This is my query:

```
Query qry=session.createQuery("select distinct company_name from Company_Info where company_name like '%"+keyword+"%' or  locations.city like '%"+keyword+"%'");
```

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved by using apache lucene search it's worked for me:

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.createIndexer(Company_Info.class).startAndWait();

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Company.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword()
        .onFields("company_name","locations.city")
        .matching(keyword)
    .createQuery();

org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Company_Info.class);

List<Company_Info> result = hibQuery.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to use is null in the HQL, (if there are parameters with null potential.) Use this:

```
String keywordTerm = keyword==null ? "is null" : "= :keyword";

Query qry=session.createQuery("select distinct company_name from Company_Info where company_name like '%"+keyword+"%' or  locations.city like '%"+keyword+"%'");

if(keyword!=null){
    qry.setParameter("keyword", keyword, Hibernate.STRING)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dark Knight :-)

Comment: Here keyword wont be null coz iam entering some thing from the form as keyword...iam not getting the record whenever any one of the filed is null in database it may be the company name or location.